# Delete Items of Recycler View in Firebase Update the Screen

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, android-recyclerview

I have a Recycler View that contains Boards(a data class) which are stored in Firebase, I want to Delete the Boards When I Swipe Left or Right on Them but I can't Figure out a Way to Do it, So it will be Very Helpful if Any One could Tell Me How To Do It or any Suggestion would be of Great Help, Thank You.

*My Adapter of Recycler View*

```
open class BoardItemAdapter(private val context: Context, private val list: ArrayList<Board>): RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {
    private var onClickListener: OnClickListener? = null
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
       return MyViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_itemboard, parent, false))
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val model = list[position]
        if(holder is MyViewHolder) {
            Glide
                .with(context)
                .load(model.image)
                .centerCrop()
                .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_nav_user)
                .into(holder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivboardimage))

            holder.itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvname).text = model.name
            holder.itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvcreatedby).text = "Created By: ${model.createdBy}"
            holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
                if(onClickListener!=null) {
                    onClickListener!!.onClick(position,model)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return list.size
    }

    interface OnClickListener {
        fun onClick(position: Int, model: Board)
    }

    fun setOnClickListener(onClickListener: OnClickListener) {
        this.onClickListener = onClickListener
    }

    private class MyViewHolder(view: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view)

}
```

*My Firebase Class*

```
class FirestoreClass: BaseActivity() {
    private val mFireStore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()

    fun registerUser(activity: SignUpActivity, userInfo: User) {
        mFireStore.collection(Constants.Users).document(getCurrentUserId()).set(userInfo,SetOptions.merge()).addOnSuccessListener {
            activity.userRegisteredSuccess()
        }.addOnFailureListener {
            Log.e(activity.javaClass.simpleName, "Error Writing Document")
        }
    }

    fun getCurrentUserId(): String {
        val currentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser
        var currentUserId = ""
        if(currentUser!=null) {
            currentUserId = currentUser.uid
        }
        return currentUserId
    }

    fun loadUserData(activity: Activity, reaBoardList: Boolean = false) {
        mFireStore.collection(Constants.Users).document(getCurrentUserId()).get().addOnSuccessListener { document ->
            val loggedInUser = document.toObject(User::class.java)
            if(loggedInUser!=null) {
                when (activity) {
                    is SignInActivity -> {
                            activity.signInSuccess(loggedInUser)
                    }
                    is MainActivity -> {
                        activity.updateNavigationUserDetails(loggedInUser,reaBoardList)
                    }
                    is MyProfileActivity -> {
                        activity.setUserDataInUI(loggedInUser)
                    }
                }
            }
        }.addOnFailureListener {
            e ->
            when (activity) {
                is SignInActivity -> {
                    activity.hideProgressDialog()
                }
                is MainActivity -> {
                    activity.hideProgressDialog()
                }
            }
            Log.e(activity.javaClass.simpleName,"Error Writin Document", e)
        }
    }

    fun updateUserProfileData(activity: Activity, userHashMap: HashMap<String,Any>) {
        mFireStore.collection(Constants.Users).document(getCurrentUserId()).update(userHashMap).addOnSuccessListener {
            Log.i(activity.javaClass.simpleName,"Profile Data Updated")
            Toast.makeText(activity,"Profile Updated Successfully!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            when(activity) {
                is MainActivity -> {
                    activity.tokenUpdateSuccess()
                }
                is MyProfileActivity -> {
                    activity.profileUpdateSuccess()
                }
            }
        }.addOnFailureListener {
            e->
            when(activity) {
                is MainActivity -> {
                    activity.hideProgressDialog()
                }
                is MyProfileActivity -> {
                    activity.hideProgressDialog()
                }
            }
            Log.e(activity.javaClass.simpleName,"Error While Creating a Board",e)
            Toast.makeText(activity,"Error When Updating the Profile!!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }

    fun createBoard(activity: CreateBoardActivity, board: Board) {
        mFireStore.collection(Constants.BOARDS).document().set(board,SetOptions.merge()).addOnSuccessListener {
            Log.e(activity.javaClass.simpleName,"Board Created Successfully!")
            Toast.makeText(activity,"Board Created Successfully",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            activity.boardCreatedSuccessfully()
        }.addOnFailureListener {
            Log.e(activity.javaClass.simpleName, "Error Writing Document")
        }
    }

    fun getBoardList(activity: MainActivity) {
        mFireStore.collection(Constants.BOARDS).whereArrayContains(Constants.ASSIGNED_TO, getCurrentUserId()).get().addOnSuccessListener {
            document->
            Log.i(activity.javaClass.simpleName, document.documents.toString())
            val boardList: ArrayList<Board> = ArrayList()
                for(i in document.documents) {
                    val board = i.toObject(Board::class.java)!!
                    board.documentId = i.id
                    boardList.add(board)
                }
            activity.populateBoardListToUI(boardList)
        }.addOnFailureListener {
            hideProgressDialog()
            Log.e(activity.javaClass.simpleName,"Error While Creating a Board",it)
        }
    }
```

*My Main Acivity*

```
class MainActivity : BaseActivity(), NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    private var binding: ActivityMainBinding? = null
    private lateinit var mUserName: String
    private lateinit var mSharedPref: SharedPreferences
    private var mainMenu: Menu? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding?.root)
        setActionBar()
        mSharedPref = this.getSharedPreferences(Constants.PROMAG_PREFRENCES, MODE_PRIVATE)
        val tokenUpdated = mSharedPref.getBoolean(Constants.FCM_TOKEN_UPDATED,false)
        if(tokenUpdated) {
            showProgressDialog("Please Wait ...")
            FirestoreClass().loadUserData(this,true)
        } else {
            FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance()
                .instanceId.addOnSuccessListener(this@MainActivity) { instanceIdResult ->
                    updateFCMToken(instanceIdResult.token)
            }
        }
        binding?.navview?.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this)
        FirestoreClass().loadUserData(this,true)
        binding?.appbar?.floatBoard?.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this@MainActivity,CreateBoardActivity::class.java)
            intent.putExtra(Constants.NAME,mUserName)
            startActivityForResult(intent, MY_BOARD_REQUEST_CODE)
        }
    }

    @Deprecated("Deprecated in Java")
    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if(resultCode==Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == MY_PROFILE_REQUEST_CODE) {
            FirestoreClass().loadUserData(this)
        } else if(resultCode==Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == MY_BOARD_REQUEST_CODE) {
            FirestoreClass().getBoardList(this)
        } else {
            Log.e("Cancelled","Cancelled")
        }
    }

    fun updateNavigationUserDetails(user: User,readBoardList: Boolean) {
        hideProgressDialog()
        mUserName = user.name
        Glide
            .with(this)
            .load(user.image)
            .centerCrop()
            .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_nav_user)
            .into(findViewById<CircleImageView>(R.id.hdoden))

        val name = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvusername)
        name.text = user.name
        if(readBoardList) {
            showProgressDialog("Please Wait ...")
            FirestoreClass().getBoardList(this)
        }
    }

    override fun onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        when(item.itemId) {
            R.id.myprof -> {
                startActivityForResult(Intent(this@MainActivity,MyProfileActivity::class.java),MY_PROFILE_REQUEST_CODE)
            }
            R.id.navsignout -> {
                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut()
                mSharedPref.edit().clear().apply()
                val intent = Intent(this@MainActivity,IntroActivity::class.java)
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
                startActivity(intent)
                finish()
            }
        }
        return true
    }

    fun populateBoardListToUI(boardList: ArrayList<Board>) {
        hideProgressDialog()
        if(boardList.size>0) {
            binding?.appbar?.llmaincontent?.rvboardlist?.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            binding?.appbar?.llmaincontent?.tvnoboardavailable?.visibility = View.GONE
            binding?.appbar?.llmaincontent?.rvboardlist?.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)
            binding?.appbar?.llmaincontent?.rvboardlist?.setHasFixedSize(true)
            val adapter = BoardItemAdapter(this,boardList)
            binding?.appbar?.llmaincontent?.rvboardlist?.adapter = adapter
            adapter.setOnClickListener(object: BoardItemAdapter.OnClickListener{
                override fun onClick(position: Int, model: Board) {
                    val intent = Intent(this@MainActivity,TaskListActivity::class.java)
                    intent.putExtra(Constants.DOCUMENT_ID,model.documentId)
                    startActivity(intent)
                }
            })
        } else {
            binding?.appbar?.llmaincontent?.rvboardlist?.visibility = View.GONE
            binding?.appbar?.llmaincontent?.tvnoboardavailable?.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        }
    }

    private fun setActionBar() {
        setSupportActionBar(binding?.appbar?.toolbarmainacivity)
        binding?.appbar?.toolbarmainacivity?.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_hamburger)
        binding?.appbar?.toolbarmainacivity?.setNavigationOnClickListener {
            if(binding?.drawerl?.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)==true) {
                binding?.drawerl?.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
            } else {
                binding?.drawerl?.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
            }
        }
    }

    fun tokenUpdateSuccess() {
        hideProgressDialog()
        val editor : SharedPreferences.Editor = mSharedPref.edit()
        editor.putBoolean(Constants.FCM_TOKEN_UPDATED,true)
        editor.apply()
        showProgressDialog("Please Wait ...")
        FirestoreClass().loadUserData(this,true)
    }

    private fun updateFCMToken(token:String) {
        val userHashMap = HashMap<String,Any>()
        userHashMap[Constants.FCM_TOKEN] = token
        showProgressDialog("Please Wait ...")
        FirestoreClass().updateUserProfileData(this,userHashMap)
    }

    override fun onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed()
        if(binding?.drawerl?.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)==true) {
            binding?.drawerl?.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
        } else {
            doubleBackToExit()
        }
    }

    companion object{
        const val MY_PROFILE_REQUEST_CODE: Int = 11
        const val MY_BOARD_REQUEST_CODE: Int = 12
    }

}
```

Comment: Probably you might want to clear the lists on the swipe. Like in Kotlin we would do list.clear() for mutable lists.

Comment: I think that this resource, [How to delete a record from Firestore on a RecylerView left/right swipe?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-delete-a-record-from-firestore-on-a-recylerview-left-right-swipe-d65d993f0baf) or using [multi-selection?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-delete-multiple-records-from-firestore-using-recyclerview-multi-selection-96108e4c6166) might help.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by the Alex mano, you can follow the [blog1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69255846/15774176) and [blog2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54959437/15774176) where brief information is provided for deletion of a single or multiple record from firestore on a recyclerview.

For more information, you can follow [thread1](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-delete-a-record-from-firestore-on-a-recylerview-left-right-swipe-d65d993f0baf) and [thread2](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-delete-multiple-records-from-firestore-using-recyclerview-multi-selection-96108e4c6166) where deletion of an item or node from the firestore on a recyclerview is explained.  Code example :

> ```
> @Override
> public void onDeleteClick(int position) {
>     Upload selectedItem = mUploads.get(position);
>     StorageReference imageRef = mStorage.getReferenceFromUrl(selectedItem.getmImageUrl());
>
>         View view = LayoutInflater.from(ShowPatientsRecords.this).inflate(R.layout.alertdelet null);
>
>         Button no = view.findViewById(R.id.dltNo);
>         Button yes = view.findViewById(R.id.dltYes);
>
>         AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(ShowPatientsRecords.this).setView(view).create();
>         dialog.setCancelable(false);
>         dialog.show();
>
>         yes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
>             @Override
>             public void onClick(View v) {
>                 Upload selectedItem = mUploads.get(position);
>                 final String selectedKey = selectedItem.getmKey();
>
>                 imageRef.delete().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
>                     @Override
>                     public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
>                         mDatabaseRef.child(selectedKey).removeValue();
>                         dialog.dismiss();
>                         Toast.makeText(ShowPatientsRecords.this, "Record deleted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
>                     }
>                 });
>             }
>         });
>
>         no.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
>             @Override
>             public void onClick(View v) {
>                 dialog.dismiss();
>             }
>         });
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: @Suryansh Singh Rajput Posted an answer, is ithelpful?